# Passing credentials to Glassfish admin web service

Tags: curl, glassfish-3

I'm learning to use the Glassfish 3 REST interface directly, since the admin web GUI is so damn slow that it's barely usable. So, for example, I do this:

```
curl -s http://localhost:4848/monitoring/domain/server/transaction-service
```

This works fine on my personal instance of Glassfish, which has a blank password for the admin user. On the production instance, it complains about "Invalid user name or password." So how do I pass the user name and password to this command?

Bonus question: I already know how to specify the credentials to `asadmin` - how do I perform the above operation with `asadmin`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GlassFish REST Interface supports basic authentication.

You would [use the '--user' option](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) for curl to authenticate your requests.

The command would look like this

```
curl --user USER:PASSWORD -s http://localhost:4848/monitoring/domain/server/transaction-service
```

If you are the admin user for your production server, you should [secure the GlassFish REST Interface](http://blogs.oracle.com/aquatic/entry/configuring_security_for_glassfish_rest) to protect the authentication data from sniffing, if it has not been configured already.

The command would look like this, after securing the interface.

```
curl --user USER:PASSWORD -s https://localhost:4848/monitoring/domain/server/transaction-service
```

You can [use asadmin get and asadmin list to view monitoring data](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/821-1751/ghmct?l=en&a=view), too.
Try

```
asadmin get --monitor get server.transaction-service.*
```

To get the value of statistics associated with the transaction service.  Remember to [set the monitoring level to HI](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/821-1751/ablvr?l=en&a=view) first.

Answer (score 0):

The GlassFish REST Interface supports basic authentication over SSL. For detail on how to secure the GlassFish REST Interface, see this [blog entry](http://blogs.oracle.com/aquatic/entry/configuring_security_for_glassfish_rest).