# Dynamically reloading jdbc-connection-pool settings

Tags: jdbc, glassfish-3, connection-pooling, chef-infra

I have a connection pool setup properly on Glassfish 3.1.2.2.  This is working properly.

My setup is to multiple slave database servers, therefore the `URL` property of my `jdbc-connection-pool`.  This one looks like so:

```
jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://my.database.host1,my.database.host2/dbName
```

Once again, functional.  We then have a `Chef` server that, when slaves are overloaded, spins up a new one.  It then modifies the `domain.xml` of my web servers to append the new host to the `URL` property.  I now have:

```
jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://my.database.host1,my.database.host2,newly.created.host/dbName
```

Our current solution is to restart Glassfish in order to have the new values taken into account.  This has the consequence that it kicks out all who have a session with said server, among other negative impacts.  **Is there a way to get these values reloaded without restarting the server?**  - On the fly/dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured this one out!  I, and I would assume many others from reading on different forums have forgotten about the RESTful admin interface to Glassfish.

By updating the URL for the connection pool via REST, I can update the value without having to reset the server instance.

Here is the cURL request I am using:

```
curl –X POST –H ”X-Requested-By: Glassfish REST HTML Interface” 
    –d “value=jdbc:mysql://my.database.host1,my.database.host2,newly.created.host/dbname” 
    –u “username”:”password” 
    https://admin.host.url:4848/management/domain/resources/jdbc-connection-pool/poolname/property/URL 
    -k
```

I have added the `-k` since my security certificate isn't in my `cacert` file and I wanted to save time for the moment.  *It would be better practice to have cURL validate your security certificate*.

#### Useful Links:

- [Oracle's Using REST Interfaces to Administer GlassFish Server](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24928/general-administration.htm#gjipx)
- [Oracle's Dotted names](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24938/dotted-names.htm#GSRFM00268)
- [Passing credentials to Glassfish admin web service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205894/686036)
- [Using cURL to automate HTTP jobs](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if you simply want to flush the database jdbc connection pool you can use the REST interface like this:

```
curl –X POST –H "X-Requested-By: GlassFish REST HTML interface" –d "appname=&id=JDBC_POOLNAME&modulename=&__remove_empty_entries__=true&=flush-connection-pool" –u "USER":"PASSWORD" http://server:port/management/domain/resources/flush-connection-pool
```